# AngularJS/Javascript: Sorting Strings With Operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I need to sort-

```
var array1 = ["AAA","BB","B+","AA+","CC","AA-","B","A","AA"];
```

After applying filter/sort I want something like –

```
var array1 = ["AAA","AA+","AA","AA-","A","BB","B+","B","CC"];
```

Here alphabets having higher precedence over operator like after soring AAA should come before AA+

How can I do it?

Comment: You can write your own sorting function, the sort function on arrays accepts an optional custom comparator, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: it all possibly variants or possibly something like `"AAB"` or `"BC+"`?

Comment: Yes we do have variants with mix alphabets

Comment: what possibly max string length? i mean how many symbols in one string like 'AAA' or 'AAAAAAAA' etc, or it unlimit?

Comment: NOTE: my answer only for string with max length = 3

Comment: Yes that is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As say above you need pass custom compare function to sort. Something like this

```
function s(a,b){
  function normalize(str){
    return str.concat(new Array(4-str.length).join(';')).replace(/[A-Z+-]/g, function($1){
      return replacer[$1] ? replacer[$1] : $1;
    });
  }

  var replacer = {
    'A' : '1',
    'B' : '2',
    'C' : '3',
    '+' : ':',
    '-' : '<'
  },

  ar = normalize(a),
  br = normalize(b);

  return ar > br ? 1
       : ar < br ? -1
       : 0;
}
```

```js
var array1 = ["AAA","BB","B+","AA+","CC","AA-","B","A","AA"];

function s(a,b){
  function normalize(str){
    return str.concat(new Array(4-str.length).join(';')).replace(/[A-Z+-]/g, function($1){
      return replacer[$1] ? replacer[$1] : $1;
    });
  }
  
  var replacer = {
    'A' : '1',
    'B' : '2',
    'C' : '3',
    '+' : ':',
    '-' : '<'
  },
  
  ar = normalize(a),
  br = normalize(b);
  
  return ar > br ? 1
       : ar < br ? -1
       : 0;
}

document.getElementById('before').innerHTML = 'unsorted: ' + array1.join();

array1.sort(s);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'sorted: ' + array1.join();
```

```html
<span id="before"></span><br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

UPDATE: a bit more generic

```
function sorting(maxLen) {
  return function s(a, b) {
    function checkLength(str, maxlen) {
      if (str.length > maxlen) {
        throw new Error('string: "' + str + '" (' + str.length + ') too long, max len: ' + maxlen);
      }
    }

    function normalize(str, maxlen) {
      return str.concat(new Array(maxlen + 1 - str.length).join(';')).replace(/[A-Z+-]/g, function($1) {
        return replacer[$1] ? replacer[$1] : $1;
      });
    }

    checkLength(a, maxLen);
    checkLength(b, maxLen);

    var replacer = {
        'A': '1',
        'B': '2',
        'C': '3',
        '+': ':',
        '-': '<'
      },
      ar = normalize(a, maxLen),
      br = normalize(b, maxLen);

    return ar > br ? 1 : ar < br ? -1 : 0;
  }
}
```

and use it function like

```
array1.sort(sorting(array1.reduce(function(a,b){return Math.max(a, b.length);},0)))
```

```js
var array1 = ["AAAA", "BB", "BBBB+", "AAA+", "CC", "AA-", "BBBB", "A", "AA"];
var array2 = ["AAAA", "BB", "BBBBB+", "AAA+", "CC", "AA-", "BBBB", "A", "AA"];

function sorting(maxLen) {
  return function s(a, b) {
    function checkLength(str, maxlen) {
      if (str.length > maxlen) {
        throw new Error('string: "' + str + '" (' + str.length + ') too long, max len: ' + maxlen);
      }
    }

    function normalize(str, maxlen) {
      return str.concat(new Array(maxlen + 1 - str.length).join(';')).replace(/[A-Z+-]/g, function($1) {
        return replacer[$1] ? replacer[$1] : $1;
      });
    }

    checkLength(a, maxLen);
    checkLength(b, maxLen);

    var replacer = {
        'A': '1',
        'B': '2',
        'C': '3',
        '+': ':',
        '-': '<'
      },
      ar = normalize(a, maxLen),
      br = normalize(b, maxLen);

    return ar > br ? 1 : ar < br ? -1 : 0;
  }
}

function test(witherror, arr, maxlen) {
  document.getElementById(witherror + 'before').innerHTML = 'unsorted: ' + arr.join();

  try {

    arr.sort(sorting(maxlen||arr.reduce(function(a,b){return Math.max(a, b.length);},0)));

    document.getElementById(witherror + 'result').innerHTML = 'sorted: ' + arr.join();

  } catch (e) {

    document.getElementById(witherror + 'result').innerHTML = e;

  }
}

test('', array1,5);
test('e', array2,5);
test('a', array2);
```

```html
<span>sample with error, string is too long</span>
<br>
<span id="ebefore"></span>
<br>
<span id="eresult"></span>
<hr>
<span>sample without error, maxlen = 5</span>
<br>
<span id="before"></span>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
<hr>
<span>sample without error</span>
<br>
<span id="abefore"></span>
<br>
<span id="aresult"></span>
```

Comment: @SumitDeshpande NOTE: my answer only for string with max length = 3

Comment: Is there is any way to make it generic with any max length?

Comment: @SumitDeshpande in this line `new Array(4-str.length)` - _4_ is `max len+1` so you can use some parameter for that

Comment: @SumitDeshpande add some kind of generic in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a custom compare function and pass it to the sort

```
array.sort(myfunc)
```

The function should return a negative, zero, or positive value, depending on the arguments .
Example function below

```
myfunc = function(a, b){
    //alphabet to be compared
    a1 = a.replace(/^[A-Z]+/,'');
    b1 = b.replace(/^[A-Z]+/,'');

    // in cases where alphabet are same , compare the full string.
    if(a1==b1 ){
         a1 = a;
         b1 = b;
    }
   if ( a1 < b1 ) return -1;
   if ( a1 > b1 ) return 1;
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: 'a1` - _string_, and `b1` - _string_, `a1-b1` equals `NaN`

Comment: By using above function I am getting pattern as - A,AA,AAA,B,BB,CC,AA+,B+,AA-  which is not matching with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try below custom function for your sort:

```
array1.sort(mySort);

function mySort(a,b){  

        var A = a;
        var B = b;
        if (A < B) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (A > B) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your answer inn ES6?

Comment: By using above function I am getting pattern as - A,AA,AA+,AA-,AAA,B,B+,BB,CC which is not matching with the expected result.

Answer (score -1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

answer here,

weight: A < + & AAA < AA+